# Are there official Epic Stats for Arch Lich Vecna?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, npc, epic-tier, villain

Vecna and his worlds-dominating plans has become a central figure in our 8-year campaign.  If I allow a meeting, I want to be ready with an awesome, God-like immortal with multiple prestige classes, Divine Rank and world-shaking POWER.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a feel for how this Q&A site works.  Is your problem to solve a lack of information in the books you have regarding how to build a being of the correct power level for Vecna?  In any case, happy gaming!

Comment: Thanks, @KorvinStarmast.  I did find some wonderful work done, in 4.0 book, OPEN GRAVES.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the Vecna statblocks found in the pre-3e adventures set before or during his apotheoses? (He technically had more than one. He's a complicated god.)

Answer (score 14):

Vecna is statted up in [Deities and Demigods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786926546) page 94 as a Cleric 20/Wizard 20 with 10 divine ranks. He commands 9th level arcane and divine spells, as well as 12 salient divine abilities, which is pretty earth-shaking.

You can find the update document that corrects the 3.0 book to be 3.5 compliant [here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111163406/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20030718a)